# 画像データセットのリサイズ

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy, keras

numpyの画像データセットをリサイズしたいです．

具体的には，numpy配列のshapeが(2000, 512, 512, 3)の画像データセットを，(2000, 256, 256, 3)のnumpy配列にリサイズしたいです．（⇒512×512の画像を256×256にリサイズ）

つきましては，何か方法を教えてくだされば幸いです．

Comment: サイズ変更は Pillow を使うのが良いらしいですよ。[Pythonで画像処理: Pillow, NumPy, OpenCVの違いと使い分け](https://note.nkmk.me/python-image-processing-pillow-numpy-opencv/), [Python, Pillowで画像を一括リサイズ（拡大・縮小）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pillow-image-resize/)

Comment: 機械学習が絡むとリサイズしない方が良いのかもしれません。[tensorflowで画像をresizeする事のリスク](https://changlikesdesktop.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/21/080722)

Answer (score 2):

Jupyterでの指定したディレクトリ内の画像のサイズを一括でリサイズするコードです。

次のセルに `IMG('image').convert('jpg').resize(256,256)` で画像のリサイズができるようになっています。

```
from  PIL import Image
import os
import shutil
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

class IMG():
    def __init__(self,dic):
        """初期化時には画像を置いてるディレクトリのパスをいれる"""
        self.directory=dic

    def convert(self,suffix):
        """拡張子を任意の拡張子に変更するメソッド
        引数には.(ドット)を除いた拡張子をいれる"""
        for i in os.listdir(self.directory):
            fp = self.directory + '/' + i 
            img=cv2.imread(fp)
            file_Path=Path(fp)
            cv2.imwrite(self.directory + '/' +file_Path.stem + '.' + suffix,img)
            if file_Path.suffix != '.jpg':
                os.remove(fp)
        return self


    def rename(self,new_file):
        """ファイル名を任意をファイル名に変更するメソッド
        引数には変更したいファイル名をいれる"""
        data=os.listdir(self.directory)
        for i, old_name in enumerate(data):
            path = self.directory + '/' + old_name
            # ファイル名の決定
            new_name = new_file + "_{0:03d}.jpg".format(i + 1)
            new_path= self.directory + '/' +new_name
            # ファイル名の変更
            os.rename(path, new_path)
        return self

    def resize(self,width,height):
        """ファイルサイズを任意のサイズに変更するメソッド
        引数には幅、高さをいれる"""
        for i in os.listdir(self.directory):
            path= self.directory + '/' + i
            img = cv2.imread(path)
            img_resize = cv2.resize(img,(width, height))
            cv2.imwrite(path,img_resize)
        return self

    def make_zip(self,zip_name):
        """ディレクトリの画像をzip化するメソッド
        引数には作成するzipファイル名をいれる"""
        shutil.make_archive(zip_name, 'zip', root_dir = self.directory)
```